# specify ENTRYPOINT during docker build

Tags: docker, dockerfile, bazel

I want to build docker images for binaries that bazel builds. Given rules_docker is deprecated and rules_oci does not seem mature especially for python, I'm putting the binaries into docker myself with some python script that calls docker.

I have a dockerfile that basically just copies over bazel's runfiles to docker. Is there a way to specify a docker's ENTRYPOINT when calling `docker build`? That way different target can share the same dockerfile but users of dockerfile do not need to specify the entrypoint, which is the behavior of `rules_docker`.

Comment: If you're putting multiple commands into a single image, you can `docker run image-name command args`, but that requires that you _not_ fix the image's `ENTRYPOINT` to a single command (providing a default `CMD` is fine).

Comment: Create a common base image and then create specific image from this with custom `ENTRYPOINT`

Comment: @Max I was hoping that I can do this with just one dockerfile, not many dockerfiles one for each ENTRYPOINT (which your solution suggests)?

Comment: If you want one Dockerfile, update your question with some examples of what you want. A solution with Linux system could be  `entrypoint startup.sh` where on your .sh you can do a series of `if`